# Global Static Class with Objects

Tags: c#, oop, static

Ok, so I know you can't have objects in a static class but i need a class that i can hold objects that are accessible from different classes. I am making a dll that will provide extended functionality to another program so i can't just inherit or pass classes around either. if need be i can just maybe make the properties of each object i need to be in the static class which would work but not be as friendly as i would like. anyone have any other ideas on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Have you considered Dependency Injection and/or the Managed Extensibility Framework?

Comment: what is the reason you say OK as your first word?

Comment: It is actually named Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, you can have objects in a static class -- they just have to be *static* objects.

For instance:

```
public static class SharedObjects
{
    private static MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass GetObj() 
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And from elsewhere in your program you can call instance methods/properties/etc.:

```
SharedObjects.GetObj().MyInstanceMethod();
```

Comment: well I did try this but i get this error which is what brought me here:


so thats why i thought you couldn't have objects in your static classes

Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'MyNameSpace.MyClass' is less accessible than method 'MyNameSpace.StaticClass.GetObj()'

Comment: In that case check the access modifier for MyClass. It needs to be public instead of private or internal.

Comment: @cferbs As Manfred said, make sure `MyClass` is declared as `public class MyClass`.

Comment: @Justin: Yes. A class needs to be public in order to be accessible from a different assembly. In the case of a nested class it needs to be public even in the case when used from within the same assembly.

Comment: and further a class used as return type in for a public method in a public class needs to be public as well

Comment: Yes that was the problem i forgot to make my object class public. 
thanks alot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a class with the accessors methods accessing a static object (or objects). The other parts of your system can use the class either as static or as a non-static. Here is the code:

```
  public class GlobalInformation {
     public static GlobalInformation CreateInstance() {
        // Factory method through GlobalInformmation.CreateInstance()
        return new GlobalInformation();
     }

     public GlobalInformation() {
        // Regular use through new GlobalInformation()
     }

     static GlobalInformation() {
        // Static initializer called once before class is used.
        // e.g. initialize values:
        _aString = "The string value";
     }

     public string AccessAString {
        get {
           return _aString;
        }
     }

     public Foo AccessAnObject() {
        return _anObject;
     }

     private static string _aString;
     private static readonly Foo _anObject = new Foo();
  }
```

Other parts of your system would use it as follows. Option 1:

```
var globalInfo = GlobalInformation.CreateInstance();
var aString = globalInfo.AssessAString;
var anObj = globalInfo.AccessAnObject();
```

Option 2:

```
var globalInfo = new GlobalInformation();
var aString = globalInfo.AssessAString;
var anObj = globalInfo.AccessAnObject();
```

Option 2 would be my preferred one (I'd remove the static factory method `CreateInstance()`) as you could change the implementation at any time including making (some of) the fields non-static. It would **appear** to be a regular class while sharing data.